# implementing a custom cast for two types in c#

Tags: c#, casting, extension-methods

I have two custom classes for which I want to implement casts between each other. I only have the DLLs of the two projects and not the code. Can I use extension methods to implement the cast or would I need to do something else?

Comment: See also the question on adding implicit conversions to existing types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754815/c-adding-implict-conversions-to-existing-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it. Anyway, do you really need the code to look like cast? Sometimes when you implement operators or casts for custom types the code may become harder to understand. I would suggest to create separate utility to convert types which would be more obvious for someone who sees the code for the first time.

Comment: by separate utility, do you mean something similar to static methods like Utility.ConvertToA(B) and Utility.ConvertToB(A) or something else?

Comment: It can be anything, depending on how you are going to use it. If you need to convert only two types then I would go with ConvertAToB. If you need to convert many different types you may want to consider some tool, like automapper suggested by Daniel.

Comment: how would the extension methods work? I tried creating a static class with a method ' public static explicit operator B(A a) { return new B(...);}' and it gives me an error User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type

Comment: As I said I don't think there is a way to implement casting with extensions. However you can implement your own extension like ConvertAToB.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you implement your own mappers between the 2 classes or use mapping tools such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use either extension methods or some other mapping. You could also use http://automapper.codeplex.com/