# Add cast to an existing class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add a cast to an existing class.

I searched and found [a question which was answered by using extensions not operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754815/c-sharp-adding-implict-conversions-to-existing-types).

When I want to declare an operator I encounter the error saying **User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type**

Does this mean I can not totally add operators to other classes as long as I do not access their source? Is there anything I am missing?

---

Edit:

```
public static explicit operator int(DateTime dt)
{
    return int.Parse(dt.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "").Replace("-", ""));
}
```

Comment: Short answer: If you don't have the source you **cannot**.

Comment: Yes - what error message says. There is no way around if you need user-defined conversion.

Comment: Give us some specifics. What do you want to cast? What do you want to cast it to?

Comment: You may consider using a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and implement `explict` operator for your decorator.

Comment: First you mention casting and then operator overloading. I think I missed something...

Comment: @JimMischel I want to cast say DateTime to int

Comment: @Areks it was my bad presentation, I meant explicit/implicit operator to implement a casting

Comment: In the case of `DateTime` and `Int`, you can write `int foo = (int)DateTime.Ticks`. Note, though, that `Ticks` is `Int64` (`long` in C#); casting to `int` will lose information.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need to be able to modify a class or struct to add an operator.

Even without the original source, you still may have some options. (Doubtful but possible.)

- If the class is marked as partial (which it probably isn't), you can create a partial class to extend the existing class and add the operator in your partial class. However (as Sriram pointed out in the comment below), partial classes must exist in the same assembly as the calling class. If you are using a class from 3rd party, chances are that is both not marked as partial and will not be in the same assembly as your own classes. (Otherwise, you would already be modifying it.) I include the partial class option just as a possible but unlikely option.
- If the class is not sealed, you could possibly derive a new class and add the operator in your derived class.
- If the class you are using is from an open source library, you can quite possibly just pull the source and make the necessary modifications to your class.
- If the class you are wanting to modify is part of a pre-packaged assembly, you could consider using a de-compiler like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to view the code in the original class and roll your own version within your code. This is probably NOT a realistic option in most cases but I offer it up anyway.

Microsoft published a simple tutorial on the topic of adding operators. It is quite dated but I think it may be helpful.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I have been coding in .NET for a long time and have never needed to add an operator. I would really like to know more about the problem you are trying to solve and see if there might be a more desirable approach.

If you do actually have a legitimate need to implement an operator, it would be very helpful if you could provide some additional detail on the use case and the limits (e.g. partial,

Comment: I disagree with point1, which is misleading. *If the class is marked as partial...* What? Partial classes are compiler magic, it is never partial in IL, btw IL doesn't have a notation for `partial`. Also note partial classes won't work outside the assembly boundaries.

Comment: If you remove point1 or atleast edit it to make it correct you own my vote.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin thanks for your thorough answer, I am implementing a DateBox user control which has a DateTime? property, but I also need to get the date in other formats, like **Jalali Date** (aka Shamsi Date) and int (ie 20140511). I had the choice of extensions, but using implicit casts is easier and provides a cleaner code. It seems like I have to go for the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an intermediate class.

```
public struct DateWrap
{
    DateTime date;

    public static implicit operator DateWrap(DateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateWrap() { date=dt };
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(DateWrap dw)
    {
        return dw.date;
    }
    public static explicit operator int(DateWrap dw)
    {
        return int.Parse(dw.date.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "").Replace("-", ""));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;

        int x=(int)(DateWrap)dt;
        // x = 5112014
    }
}
```

or

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateWrap dw=DateTime.Now;

        int x=(int)dw;
        // x = 5112014
    }
```